# Is QuantLib-SWIG feature complete?

Tags: c#, c++, quantlib

I'm just starting out looking at getting QuantLib working with our C# project using the SWIG bindings provided.

I now have things working, but I'm trying to set up a matrix then perform a Cholesky decomposition on it. This routine is present in Quantlib (search for Cholesky in http://quantlib.org/reference/class_quant_lib_1_1_matrix.html#ae99bf007dfbac44521a082ca343c4160), but C# seems completely unable to find it.

I have tried calling straight `CholeskyDecomposition(myMatrix)` with QuantLib in the Using clauses as well as scanning down the list of what Intellisense suggests after typing `QuantLib.` in code.

Having a scan through the SWIG files, I can't see Cholesky mentioned in the text anywhere which leads me to suspect that this call may not be included.

As we're just about to decide whether to start using this library, I'd therefore like to check that the SWIG files have a complete set of QuantLib calls and if not, whether there is a list of calls that are in the C++ code but not handled by SWIG? (Of course, if SWIG does contain the Cholesky call, then how to actually call it would help too!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the SWIG bindings are not feature-complete. Contributors that provide new features for the C++ library don't always provide the bindings (or can't; not everybody is familiar with SWIG and the tricks we're playing in the interfaces), so they fall behind. Features are added piecewise: sometimes a user needs a missing function, exports it and contributes it; or other times, someone asks for a missing function and someone finds the time to write it. As you might expect, the first case is more frequent.

As far as I know, there's no list of unhandled calls. It would suffer of the same problem; someone adding a new feature to the C++ library would have to remember to keep it in sync...

Comment: Great, thanks for the reply - pretty much as I thought. Would love to help, but don't think my C++ is up to the task at the moment!